# Election JS Close one window and open new window

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-packager

I am new to electron js. I have a scenario to show a loading/splash screen and then show the login screen.

here is my `main.js`

```
// necessary modules for electron application

// importing electron
const { create } = require("domain");
const electron = require("electron");
// initilizing app
const app = electron.app;
// adding window to view
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;
// path module to build file path
const path = require("path")
// to make sure we are using a proper url
const url = require("url")

let {ipcMain} = electron


let toQuit = true; // important to quit
let category = 'main_window' // default window


let win;


app.on("ready", ()=>{
    "use strict";
    createWindow();
});


app.on("closed", () => {
  "use strict";
  win = null;
})

app.on('window-all-closed',()=>{
   "use strict";
    if(process.platform !== 'darwin'){
        app.quit();
    }
})


app.on("activate", () => {
  if (win === null) {
    createWindow();
  }
});




function createWindow() {

  "use strict";
  var height;
  var width;
  var address;
  var frame; 
  var removeMenu;
  var title, backgroundColor; 

  switch (category) {
    case "main_window":
      height = 200; //Initialize size of BrowserWindow
      width = 500; //Initialize size of BrowserWindow
      frame = false;
      removeMenu = true;
      backgroundColor = "#ccc";
      address = "Views/SplashScreen/index.html"; //Initialize the address or the file location of your HTML
      break;
    case "login":
      height = 600; //Initialize size of BrowserWindow
      width = 400; //Initialize size of BrowserWindow
      frame = true;
      removeMenu = true;
      title = "Login"
      address = "Views/Login/index.html"; //Initialize the address or the file location of your HTML
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }

  win = new BrowserWindow({
    height: height, //height and width of BrowserWindow
    width: width, //height and width of BrowserWindow
    minHeight: height, //minimum height and width of BrowserWindow, you can remove this if you want
    minWidth: width, //minimum height and width of BrowserWindow, you can remove this if you want
    frame: frame,
    backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false,
      enableRemoteModule: true,
    },
  });
  win.loadURL(
    url.format({
      pathname: path.join(__dirname, address),
      protocol: "file",
      slashes: true,
    })
  );

  // enabling web dev tools
  win.webContents.openDevTools({
    mode: "detach",
  });

  // remove default top menu
  win.removeMenu(removeMenu);

  win.on("ready-to-show", () => {
    win.show();
    win.focus();
  });

  win.on("closed", (e) => {
     e.preventDefault(); //We have to prevent the closed event from doing it.
     if (toQuit) {
       console.log("I am called")
       //if the value of toQuit is true, then we want to quit the entire application
       win = null;
       app.exit(); //quit or exit the entire application
     } else {
       console.log("hide called");
      
       win.hide(); //just hide the BrowserWindow and don't quit the entire application
       toQuit = true; //reset the value of toQuit to true
     }
  });
}


//call this function from your any Javascript
ipcMain.on('createBrowserWindow', function (e, cat) {
    "use strict";
    category = cat; //get the category of window on which we want to show
    toQuit = false; //set the value to false, meaning we don't want to close the entire application but just hide the current BrowserWindow
    createWindow(); //call this function over and over again
});
```

and the `splashscreen.js`

```
const ipcRender = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

let count = 1;
let porgressBar = document.getElementById("progressbar");

let i = 70;
let interval = setInterval(()=>{
    if(i >= 400){
        clearInterval(interval);
        ipcRender.send("createBrowserWindow", "login");
    }
    porgressBar.style.width = i + "px";
    ran = Math.floor(Math.random() * (75 - 0 + 1)) + 0;
    console.log(ran);
    i = i+ran
},500);
```

Till now what I achieved is that, I am able to open the new window but the previous window is unable to close. I have tried several methods from stack overflow solutions but none of them worked.

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "electron-sms",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^17.1.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@electron/remote": "^2.0.8"
  }
}
```

Any workaround, please.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution to my problem.

In Electron Version >= 16

Install the `@electron-remote` using npm `npm i @electron/remote`. as remote has been removed in electron Version 14 and later.

secondly, Add the initialize `electron-remote` using this `require("@electron/remote/main").initialize();`

**Example**

```
const electron = require("electron");
// initilizing app
const app = electron.app;
// adding window to view
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow;
// path module to build file path
const path = require("path")
// to make sure we are using a proper url
const url = require("url")
**require("@electron/remote/main").initialize();**

let {ipcMain} = electron


let toQuit = true; // important to quit
let category = 'main_window' // default window
```

**enable webcontents** in main.js

`require("@electron/remote/main").enable(win.webContents);`

in your renderer,js call it as

`require("@electron/remote").getCurrentWindow().close();`

You are done!

Happy Coding :)